# JQuery Flip is not working on ie7 or ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I use this http://progtuts.info/downloads/JQueryFlip/ and edit it with blow but its not working on any IE.  Please also help in me to run this on IE7 the original is working perfectly on all browsers, if any one have other same example please share with me.

```
<div id="flipBox" class="flipBox">
  <div id="Div1" name="div_3" style="display: block;" class="classdiv"> Div 1 lookup </div>
  <div id="Div2" name="div_3" style="display: none;" class="classdiv"> Div 2 lookup </div>
  <div id="Div3" name="div_3" style="display: none;" class="classdiv"> Div  3 lookup </div>
  <div id="Div4" name="div_3" style="display: none;" class="classdiv"> Div 4 lookup </div>
</div>
<a id="Btn1" href="#">Btn</a> | <a id="Btn2" href="#">Btn</a> | <a id="Btn3" href="#">Btn</a> | <a id="Btn4" href="#">Btn</a>

<script type="text/javascript">    
  $( "#Btn1" ).click(function(){

      $(".classdiv").hide();
       $("#Div1").show();
       flip_func('lr','','','');   
       return false;     

  });

  $( "#Btn2" ).click(function(){

      $(".classdiv").hide();
       $("#Div2").show();
       flip_func('lr','','','');   
       return false;     

  });

  $( "#Btn3" ).click(function(){

      $(".classdiv").hide();
       $("#Div3").show();
       flip_func('lr','','','');   
       return false;     

  });

  $( "#Btn4" ).click(function(){

      $(".classdiv").hide();
       $("#Div4").show();
       flip_func('lr','','','');   
       return false;     

  });

  var old_content = $( "#flipBox" ).html();

  function flip_func(direction,color,speed,content){

      if(direction == ''){
          direction = 'rl';
      }
      if(color == ''){
          color = ''
      }
      if(speed == ''){
          speed = '1000';
      }

      $("#flipBox").flip({
                      direction: direction,
                      color: color,
                      speed: speed,
                      //content: content,
      });          
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any console.log statements in your code? That WILL break older versions of IE. Try opening developer tools F12, and try it then. If it works, that is the issue. Might be something to try.

Comment: "edit it with blow", what's `blow`?  "the original is working perfectly on all browsers", so why did you edit it?

Answer (score 1):

What version of jQuery do you use ? The 2.x version broke support for older browsers such as IE8 and previous.

http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: I am using jQuery 2.0 and its also conflict 

`code`<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      // Load jQuery
      //google.load("jquery", "1"); 
    </script>

Comment: Revert to jQuery 1.10. It's the same API, but 2.x is a bit more lightweight since it dropped support for older browsers.

Comment: On IE7 /IE8, bring up the Developer Console with F12 and watch the Console. Is there any error message when you try executing the method ?

Comment: IE Errors...

SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined 
jquery.widget.min.js, line 6 character 1
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined 
metro.min.js, line 1 character 69
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined 
metro-calendar.js, line 3 character 1
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined 
metro-datepicker.js, line 3 character 1
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined 
metro-carousel.js, line 1 character 1
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
beta, line 450 character 4
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'carousel' 
beta, line 464 character 5

Comment: Have you included jQuery after your script ? Because it would need to be before.

Comment: Hi Gretro, how are you? Pls check blow this is my all head code. I am awaiting for your kind help.  
    
<head>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery v2.0.1  -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/metro.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1"); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flip-plugin/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flip-plugin/jquery.flip.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: You are loading jQuery at least twice (which is not good). You either take it from your own server `<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>`, or you take it from Google `google.load("jquery", "1");`, but not both. Also, please download jQuery 1.10 instead of 2.0.1 to support IE6-IE8 as you desire.

Comment: Thanks for reply dear. The problem is that I need both JQuery version in same page as I am using Metro UI CSS 2.0.